# Debugger not working for Flash Builder 4

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder

I have a situation in Adobe Flash Builder 4, there is a debug mode in the software but whenever i click on it; it throws me an error saying

```
"C:\WINDOWS\system32\Macromed\Flash\Flash32_11_2_202_160.ocx

Flash Builder cannot locate the required debugger version of Adobe Flash Player. You might need to install the debugger version of the Flash Player or reinstall Flash Builder.

Do you want to try to debug with the current version?"
```

I dont know what is this, there was no debugger attached with Flash Builder and i have Flash Player installed on my system.

```
(I have a file named FlashUtil32_11_2_202_160_ActiveX.dll on this path "C:\WINDOWS\system32\Macromed\Flash\")
```

Any ideas much appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens sometimes due to corrupt flash player (debugger) or heap memory allocation.

If you restart the flash builder and clean build the project it works sometimes.

OR

Follow http://forums.adobe.com/message/4057195
Uninstall the existing flash player and install the latest one according to your OS.

Comment: I tried restarting and cleaning the build project but didnt work :( Stucking @ 57%

Answer (score 0):

You can download debug player [here](http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html)

- **ActiveX control content debugger** is for Internet Explorer
- **Plugin content debugger** if for other browsers
- **Projector content debugger** is standalone version

Comment: I will try downloading this and let you know.